# Melt a dataframe into another with not unique values

Tags: r

I have a df with unique rows

```
df  <- data.frame(id = c("A","B","C"), D = c(1,0,1), E = c(1,0,1), F = c(1,1,0))
```

another dataframe has not unique values like the following.

```
df2  <- data.frame(id = c("A","A","A","B","B","C"))
```

The key between these two dataframes is the id columns.

Is there any possible way to melt/merge this to dataframes into one like the following output?

```
dfinal  <- data.frame(id = c("A","A","A","B","B","C"), D = c(1,1,1,0,0,1), E = c(1,1,1,0,0,1), F = c(1,1,1,1,1,0))
> 
> dfinal
  id A B C
1  A 1 1 1
2  A 1 1 1
3  A 1 1 1
4  B 0 0 1
5  B 0 0 1
6  C 1 1 0
```

Answer (score 1):

just use the merge function:

```
merge(df2,df)
  id D E F
1  A 1 1 1
2  A 1 1 1
3  A 1 1 1
4  B 0 0 1
5  B 0 0 1
6  C 1 1 0
```